# Is there a wifi MIDI controller keyboard?

Tags: midi, mac, wireless, ipad

I own a M-Audio Axiom which I plug into my MacBook Pro to use MainStage (part of Logic Studio). Recently I bought an iPad and downloaded some "controller apps". What most surprised my is that those apps send MIDI data over wi-fi to my Mac. No USB connection needed.

After seeing the light, I'm now wanting to eliminate as much cables from my setup as possible. So, I'm looking for a MIDI controller keyboard (similar to Axiom) which connects to a wi-fi network and sends all MIDI data over wi-fi.

I've googled for it, but found nothing. Does anyone know a controller with such capabilities?

Comment: I found this gadget http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/MidAir.html which might work. But I would prefer the wifi capability being integrated in the controller.

Comment: also... since there won't be an USB cable powering the controller it should work on batteries

Comment: When you do find it, try using an ad-hoc network, which will reduce the number of hops and therefore the latency.... Also this question reminds of these terrible devices (I remember them in the context of the Zendrum): http://www.zendrum.com/resource-site/Kenton.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CME UF-series](http://www.cme-pro.com/products-list/product-uf50607080.html) keyboards support a built-in [MIDI-over-wireless](http://www.cme-pro.com/en/product-detail.php?product_id=1) system.

My first guess was the [Rockband wireless keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003RS19N4). Unfortunately, it [doesn't appear to transmit MIDI data over its bluetooth connection](http://www.cycling74.com/forums/topic.php?id=33283).

If you are up for a DIY project, here are some instructions on [building a wireless MIDI link using XBee radios](http://www.ladyada.net/make/xbee/midibee.html). Should be able to fit inside the case of most MIDI controllers.

The EMU [Shortboard](http://www.creative.com/emu/products/product.aspx?category=922&pid=19165) and [Longboard](http://www.creative.com/emu/products/product.aspx?category=922&pid=19112) are worth a look. They can be [wireless](http://www.creative.com/emu/products/product.aspx?category=902&pid=18609) and can run on batteries.

Comment: This is technically not an answer to the question as none of these solutions actually use Wi-Fi (Wireless LAN). However, Wi-Fi would probably not be suited well anyway as it tends to have rather longer latencies than acceptable for live MIDI, being designed with emphasis on high data throughput (which is completely irrelevant for the tiny amounts of data you can possibly send from a master keyboard) rather than real-time performance.